# Could not get base to fixed frame transform, Lookup would require extrapolation into the future

Tags: ros, transform, laser

I'm trying to figure out what is causing this message.

I am using an rplidar, and launching like so:

```
roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch
```

Then I create a transform (which does not actually do any transforming)

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0  base_link laser 50
```

Then I start the laser scanner matcher:

```
rosrun laser_scan_matcher laser_scan_matcher_node \
       _use_imu:=false \
       _use_odom:=false \
       _base_frame:=base_link \
       _fixed_frame:=odom \
       _max_correspondence_dist:=0.05 \
       _max_linear_correction:=0.10 \
       _max_angular_correction_deg:=15.0 \
       _kf_dist_linear:=0.1 \
       _kf_dist_angular:=0.12



[ WARN] [1709143680.415580308]: Could not get base to fixed frame transform, "odom" passed to lookupTransform argument fixed_frame does not exist.
[ WARN] [1709143680.549176157]: Could not get base to fixed frame transform, Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1709143680.298256636, but only time 1709143680.138698816 is in the buffe, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [odom]
[ WARN] [1709143680.696227628]: Could not get base to fixed frame transform, Lookup would require extrapolation 0.149228720s into the future.  Requested time 1709143680.447485447 but the latest data is at time 1709143680.298256636, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [odom]
```

These are all running on the same node, so I know it's not a "time sync" issue.

After launching, here is the TF tree:
[image]

If I add another TF:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0  base_link odom 100
```

This seems to make the laser scanner happy UNTIL I start up slam_gmapping.   Then the warning scrolls the console again.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to attach your tfs tree using any tool like rqt? The problem seems to be the tf from odom to base_link. I would suggest to make another static tf for odom to base_link as well to see if the error persists.

Comment: @ÁngeLoGa Added it to the post. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0):

So, after reviewing your updated answer, I have to confirm several things. You are using laser_scan_matcher to calculate your `odom -> base_link` tf and then gmapping should publish the `map -> odom` tf. What seems wrong is the first tf as I mentioned in the comment. Is it normal that the last update of that tf is 10 seconds after the previous one? Could you check if the publication of the tf is periodically and stable? Also, I checked if there was any parameters which normally modify the timeout for the tf, but I didn't see it, which is a pitty.

Lastly, I suppose the warning you are showing comes from gmapping, right? In case it is from the laser_scan_matcher, there should be some parameters that are not being entered correctly. If you work only with the laser_scan_matcher (being the parent frame "odom"), do you see any issues regarding the tf publication or anything else?